# When is the typical end of interview invitations for faculty positions?

Tags: faculty-application, interview

Is there a date when interview invitations stop going out? Some said that interview invitations will come between mid-Jan and mid-Feb, so can an applicant  assume that by March or mid-March there will be no more interview invitations?

Comment: I don't have enough for a full-blown answer, but, on the last cycle, I got a request for a Skype interview at the end of March and an invite for an on-campus visit in early April. This is probably not typical, though.

Comment: It varies a lot by discipline and institution.  At my institution we're nearly done hiring in some departments and just starting on campus interviews in other departments (like mine.)  The more prestigious institutions will typically make earlier offers, while the less prestigious places tend to go later (to avoid time wasting top candidates that they wouldn't be able to get anyway.)

Comment: Hiring times are not that tightly coupled with the funding cycle or the academic year.  Sometimes people find pots of money to bridge before the funding comes through or the post is vacant, so the job is already stitched up beforehand; sometimes several rounds of advertise-interview-offer happen before anyone gets recruited.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think there is a single answer here. Some schools start their interview process in late fall, and other schools don't even conduct preliminary interviews until the end of February. In addition, there's always the possibility that nobody accepts their initial offers, in which case they may want to start a new round of interviews. So basically, you can get an interview request until you get a rejection letter.

However, I would suspect that the bulk of interview requests go out by late February.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the field you're in. I'm familiar with Math and there, all research schools probably finish hiring at the end of February. We might have sent offers in March, but I don't think we ever invited anyone after mid-February.

Of course, the timeline is completely different for senior hires where there is, essentially, no timeline at all. But I assume that's not what you were asking for.

Answer (score 2):

As some folks have mentioned, it will depend greatly based on the field. My own field doesn't even have a well-defined cycle - there are job announcements posted essentially continuously, which means a similarly continuous trickle of possible interview invitations, and some announcements are held open a remarkably long time.

It may be useful to consult someone specifically in your field, such as your advisor, or another faculty member you trust.

Answer (score 0):

In economics for assistant prof positions, the interviews are all during the AEA/ASSA conference during the first week of January, or similar conferences in Britain and Europe. The interview invitations are usually out by Dec. 15.

Varies by discipline, as mentioned in the other answers.